# How to write CAML queries filtering on ModStat (Approved, Rejected) when using Language Packs?

Tags: caml-query, localization

When using content approval the CAML for retrieving (say) just Approved Items is

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus" />
      <Value Type="ModStat">Approved</Value>
    </Eq>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

However this will only work in English language sites - for French it would be "Approuvé" for example.

Obviously I can put together resource files for all the different supported languages but is there an easier way, either

a) A hidden field that isn't translated (perhaps a numeric indicator)

b) A way in the object model to get the translated work for each approval status?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open fieldswss.xml you find the declaration of this field

```
<Field ID="{fdc3b2ed-5bf2-4835-a4bc-b885f3396a61}"
        Name="_ModerationStatus"
        SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"
        StaticName="_ModerationStatus"
        Group="_Hidden"
        ColName="tp_ModerationStatus"
        RowOrdinal="0"
        ReadOnly="TRUE"
        Type="ModStat"
        DisplayName="$Resources:core,Approval_Status;"
        Hidden="TRUE"
        CanToggleHidden="TRUE"
        Required="FALSE">
        <CHOICES>
            <CHOICE>0;#$Resources:core,402;</CHOICE>
            <CHOICE>1;#$Resources:core,400;</CHOICE>
            <CHOICE>2;#$Resources:core,401;</CHOICE>
            <CHOICE>3;#$Resources:core,403;</CHOICE>
            <CHOICE>4;#$Resources:core,404;</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>
        <Default>0</Default>
    </Field>
```

I think thatt you can use something like this:

```
string str = "$Resources:402";
string status = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString(str , "core", (uint)culture.LCID);
```

Answer (score 17):

Alexanders answer is probably the way to go, but if you're being lazy and **you're using 2010** (it doesn't work on 2007) you can use the numeric values.

```
0 = Approved
1 = Rejected
2 = Pending
```

So Approved is

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus" />
      <Value Type="ModStat">0</Value>
    </Eq>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 12):

And adding on Alexander and Ryan's answers, if you rely on the numeric value, watch out for the "4" value, that's the "scheduled" one when the contributor publishes something but SharePoint keep it in temporary draft mode until it enters its publication time frame.

```
0 = Approved
1 = Rejected
2 = Pending
3 = Draft
4 = Scheduled
```

A published and approved item might thus be in draft state just because it is not currently in schedule. Depending on your business case it might or it might not make sense to display them.

For further explanations regarding that unfrequent status : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sanjaynarang/archive/2009/02/19/relationships-between-moderation-approval-status-scheduling-versions-and-workflows.aspx

Hope it helped as well.